# Простонародные и аристократические русские имена

Tags: общие-вопросы, ономастика

Точнее, конечно, они, как правило, не русские по происхождению, но это в данном случае не важно.
Просто, подумалось: а по какому принципу определились простонародные имена и аристократические? Ведь всех называли по православным святцам, но в дворянской среде редко можно было встретить Матрену, Фрола или Емельяна. Есть ли тут какая-то закономерность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще о классовом разделении имён на Руси можно писать долго. Начиная с варяжских (Рюрик, Ольга), продолжая составными княжескими (Ярослав, Владимир, Святополк) и далее. Главным признаком классовой принадлежности долгое время была фамилия, так как имел её далеко не каждый и значила она намного больше, чем сейчас. Что касается самих имён, то тут уместнее говорить о моде на имена и некоторых общих тенденциях, чем дифференциации. Среди боярских имён можно увидеть и Василия, и Захара. Есть, кстати, даже повесть XVII века о дворянине Фроле Скобееве. Если брать XVIII-XIX вв., то бросающейся в глаза разницы имён аристократов и крестьян мы не обнаружим. Аристократы меньше использовали  распространённые имена Иван и Василий, а если не рассматривать частоту употребления, то в целом имена-то одни и те же.

Несколько выделялись из этого фона дворовые слуги (лакеи и прочая обслуга). Те стремились отделится из общей массы крестьян и имена использовали более затейливые, Параскева, Фрол, Филипп, Демид, Фирс и прочие. Видимо из-за дворовой прислуги у вас и возникло впечатление существенного различия имён.

Подробнее о именах XIX века можно прочитать в этой [статье](http://www.demoscope.ru/weekly/2010/0421/analit04.php).

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как насчёт закономерности, а аристократические имена здесь: http://waylux.ru/imena_korolevskie.html   Олег и Валентина Световид. А вообще об именах здесь: http://www.familii.ru/onomastika/antroponimica/1157-imenanabereste Был христианский "именник" и мирской. Вероятно, аристократические, официальные, из мирского, бытового, не брали, а собственно "аристократических" не было, просто официальные имена по святцам. А вообще, сейчас всё переменилось. Вот Татьяна-простонародное имя, как для нас сейчас Фёкла.

Comment: Брали из мирского и аристократы (те же Святополки и Ярополки), другое дело, что дохристианские имена со временем использовать перестали вовсе.